# Birt: Retrieve user information from session

Tags: session-variables, birt

Can someone please give a bit detail on how can I retrieve the user information in report parameter in Birt. I have implemented form based authentication in tomcat and I am using birtviewer as a standalone app. I have not embedded it into any application

How can I retrieve the session information like username etc. Is there any default variable where the birt stores session info? If I was embedding it into a servelet or any application, I could have set the session variable but in this case how can I retrieve the session info like username?

Arif

Comment: this link has solution for your problem.  https://wiki.eclipse.org/Retrieve_Session_information_in_Script_%28BIRT%29

Answer (score 0):

i acquired with;

```
reportContext.getHttpServletRequest().getSession().getAttribute("currentSessionInfo");
```

ref: [Eclipse forums](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/79069/)